# Question participle phrase "compared to"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> "There was a 10% increase in inventory in first quarter of 2017, **compared to the end of 2016.**"

Is the participle phrase "compared...2016" functioned as an adjective to "there"?

Comment: No, and it's not a participial phrase. "Compared" is a preposition (but keep it hush, since not many people know that). So the expression "compared to the end of 2016" is a preposition phrase functioning as an adjunct (an optional element in clause structure). Why is is it a preposition, not a verb? Mainly because there is no understood subject, but also because it can't inflect for tense.

Comment: @BillJ Shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @user178049 If I get time, I'll put it up as an answer.

Comment: @BillJ I beat you to it. I tried my best to write the answer but please free to point out my mistakes or edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might think it's a participial phrase with a passive meaning for the reason that it takes the *-ed* suffix. This analysis, unfortunately, can't work. It's possible for a word category (traditionally called 'part of speech') to share a 'shape' with other categories. The word [like](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like) for example, can be a verb, an adjective, or a preposition.

One of the most distinctive properties of a prepositional phrase is that it doesn't have to be related to the subject in the main clause when functioning as an adjunct.<sup>†</sup> Compare:

> **Adjective Phrase**
>
> [i] Tired of the ship, the captain saw an island on which to land.
>
> [ii] *Tired of the ship, there was a small island.
>
> **Verb phrase**
>
> [iii] Owing money to my stupid bank, I have to live very frugally.
>
> [iv] *Owing money to my stupid bank, there's no money for the rent.
>
> **Prepotional Phrase**
>
> [v] Ahead of the ship, the captain saw an island on which to land.
>
> [vi] Ahead of the ship, there was a small island.
>
> <sub>All examples are taken from *The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language* (Huddleston and Pullum, 2002: 604-605)</sub>

*Tired of the ship* in [i] is an adjective phrase headed by the adjective *tired*. It's an adjective because it's gradable, and hence can be modified by *very*, *very tired*. In [ii], the sentence is ungrammatical because the subject in the main clause does not relate to the adjective phrase *tired of the ship*; the subject is a dummy pronoun which has no semantic content.

The same happens to the second pair, the verb phrase needs to be related the subject in the main clause, which cannot be a dummy pronoun. So [iii] is grammatical, but [iv] is not.

In [v] and [vi], *ahead of the ship* is a prepositional phrase headed by the preposition *ahead*. Unlike the first and the second pair, the lattermost sentence is perfectly grammatical even though the subject in the main clause is a dummy pronoun *there*.

*Compared to the end of 2016* in your sentence is therefore a prepositional phrase headed by the preposition *compared*.

> **There** was a 10% increase in inventory in first quarter of 2017, compared to the end of 2016.
>
> <sub>(The subject in the main clause is the pronoun *there.*)</sub>

Some people might disagree with this on the grounds that prepositions must take a noun phrase as a complement. This is untrue; prepositions allow a wide range of complement types.

- He laughed at **the old man**. (A noun phrase)
- It depends on **how you say it**. (A clause)
- We hadn't met until **recently**. (An adverb phrase)
- That strikes me as **wrong**. (An adjective phrase)

So we can say *to the end of 2016* is a prepositional phrase that functions as a complement of the preposition *compared*.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Technically, *prepositional phrases* functioning as adjuncts do not require a 'predicand'. I refrain from using this term; many people are unfamiliar with it and you might confuse it with 'predicate'.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I understand better now

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down.  Start with "There was a 10% increase."  Pretend that's the whole sentence, because everything else is just additional description.  It's basically the same thing as saying "A 10% increase happened." or "A 10% increase there was."  And, further, we can understand that "10%" modifies "increase" so "10%" is just an adjective, and the fundamental sentence is "There was an increase." or "An increase happened." or "An increase there was."

In "there was an increase" the word "there" is just a pronoun - a placeholder, the word "was" is the (passive) verb, and "increase" is the subject of the sentence.  That's why I was able to rearrange the sentence moving "there" or removing it entirely and swapping "was" for "happened" and I kept the same meaning, because a pronoun and a passive verb are easily replaceable since they are not that important to the meaning of a sentence.

From the above analysis it's easy to understand that really everything else in the sentence is modifying "increase".

- "An increase there was, of 10%,"
- prepositional phrase "in inventory"
- prepositional phrase "in first quarter of 2017,"
- adjective phrase "compared to the end" + prepositional phrase "of 2016" (to be precise "of 2016" modifies "end" but as shown everything else is modifying "increase")

So the phrase beginning with "compared" modifies "increase" which is why compared is a past participle (formed from a verb and used, in this case, as an adjective).

From dictionary.com:

> "Following the past participle *compared*, either to or with is used
>   regardless of whether differences or similarities are stressed or
>   whether the things compared belong to the same or different classes:
>   Compared with (or to ) the streets of 18th-century London, New York's
>   streets are models of cleanliness and order."