# the category of ‘when’ in ‘when compared to other bicycles’

Tags: grammar

My inquiry below is related to the following link;
[Question participle phrase "compared to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126728/question-participle-phrase-compared-to)

I note BillJ’s and Mohd’s comment - ‘compared to the end of 2016’ in "There was a 10% increase in inventory in first quarter of 2017, compared to the end of 2016." is not a participial phrase but a preposition phrase.

When I follow their opinion, I parse each sentence below as follows;

(1) `Compared to other bicycles`, his price was too high. (a preposition phrase)

(2) `When compared to other bicycles`, his price was too high. (when + a preposition phrase, and a preposition phrase together with 'when')

(3) `When it was compared to other bicycles`, his price was too high. (an ordinary adverb clause led by a subordinating conjunction ‘when’)

When I parse the three parts above that way, I am wondering if the ‘when’ of (2) is a subordinating conjunction or a preposition meaning ‘on occasions when’.

Would appreciate your responses.

Comment: In modern grammar, "when" is classed as a preposition typically meaning something like "on occasions when". Depending on context, it can also mean "at the time at which", though that is not the case here.

Comment: @BillJ really glad to see your comment. Would you explain more to me especially about the function of 'when' of (2) above?

Comment: In the cited contexts, ***when*** looks to me like a conjunction, more or less directly replaceable by ***if***. It doesn't really have much to do with the passage of or points in time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers appreciate your comment. Do you mean 'the sentence (2) and (3)' by 'the cited contexts'? Especially for (2) above, I'm wondering if 'When compared to other bicycles' could be a preposition phrase together with 'when' or a dangling participle clause.

Comment: when compared to the price of other bicycles, his price was too high.

Comment: @deepcosmos: I'm not really interested in whether you call things prepositions or conjunctions. I only posted the comment in case it might help you understand what your text *means*, not how you should *label* it. I don't see any dangling participles, though.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as a business intelligence analyst as well as a native British English speaker, your example of "*there was a 10% increase in inventory in the first quarter of 2017, compared to the end of 2016*" sounds plain wrong. The idiomatic way to express this would be "*there was a 10% increase over the previous quarter*". It is a tautology to say that any measurement of change is "in comparison" to another period. Of course it is - how else could change be measured? It would be like saying "*I travelled 10 miles when comparing my start position to my end position*".

The same issue exists in all your other examples.

> Compared to other bicycles, the price was too high.

"***Too** high*" can only mean that it is higher than some fixed point - perhaps a personal budget. That is relative. What is too high for one person might not be too high for another. It makes no sense to say this "in comparison" to other bicycles - if the price of one bike is too high for you, what does it matter what other bikes cost?

If you mean simply that the bike is more expensive than other *comparable* bikes, then you'd just say:

> Compared to other bicycles, the price was high.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Would you give me another response to my 3 parses in the original post, since especially for (2) above I'm wondering if 'When compared to other bicycles' could be a preposition phrase together with 'when' or a dangling participle clause.

Comment: @deepcosmos I would correct all three the same way, because, despite the differences you have put into them, they are all fundamentally wrong.

Comment: "there was a 10% increase in inventory in the first quarter of 2017, compared to the last quarter of 2016"

Comment: @lambie Completely wrong, for two reasons. Firstly, it sounds like you're comparing the increase (eg there was an increase in both quarters). You don't compare the increase - you compare two periods to *measure* the increase. We say "an increase *over*". And secondly, why state which quarter you are comparing it to? If it isn't the last quarter, or some other comparable period, then it might not be an increase. What if it went up, then down, then up, then down.... its an increase compared to one, a decrease compared to another?! That's NOT how business intelligence works.

Comment: "there was a 10% increase in inventory in the first quarter of 2017, compared to that of the last quarter of 2016". *Easily fixed*. There's nothing wrong with too high. A price can be high but not necessarily too high... Over the previous quarter is the simplest, you are right there.

Comment: @lambie wrong again. If something is too high, it's too high. No comparison is needed. Likewise, if no comparison was done, would it be still be 'too high'? If you could only afford £200K and you looked at one house priced at £250K, it would be "too high". Not in comparison to other houses, but too high because of your financial limit. And if you found a house priced £180K, but all other comparable houses were £150K, you'd say it was "high". Not "too high" because you can still afford it.

Comment: I disagree with you. Highness can be compared/comparable. **When in fact  you say "this house is too high" it might just be that you are not in the market at all**. You just deem the house to be too expensive in terms of market value as you look at them in pictures online with a friend. It is merely your opinion. Like looking at clothes in a shop: This [item] one is too expensive.

Comment: @lambie You've just proved my point. All your examples are opinion-based. It's too expensive *in your opinion*. If someone else buys the item you thought was too expensive, were you wrong? No. And if a house is "too high" then maybe it's just on top of a hill. Words are important.

Comment: Something like "Compared to other bicycles, the price was too high" is very common. I'd interpret it to mean "I didn't really know if the price was too high or not at first, but when I looked at other bicycles, I realised the price was too high for what I was getting with this bicycle." It's common to qualify "too high"; without qualification the phrase is meaningless (too high for what?)

Comment: @StuartF Common doesn't make it right. And you've clearly not read my answer, because I'm not saying you shouldn't qualify "too high". It's just incorrect to do it the way you are saying to do it. Qualifying it properly would be "*it's too expensive for my budget*". But in comparison to other things, it can't be "too" high. Maybe the others are too low? I'm in charge of two levels of data analysts including 'senior' analysts. If anyone talked this kind of rubbish at interview they wouldn't be getting a job with me.